# Dealing with negative values in sklearn MultinomialNB

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multinomial

I am normalizing my text input before running MultinomialNB in sklearn like this:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5, stop_words='english', use_idf=True)
lsa = TruncatedSVD(n_components=100)
mnb = MultinomialNB(alpha=0.01)

train_text = vectorizer.fit_transform(raw_text_train)
train_text = lsa.fit_transform(train_text)
train_text = Normalizer(copy=False).fit_transform(train_text)

mnb.fit(train_text, train_labels)
```

Unfortunately, MultinomialNB does not accept the non-negative values created during the LSA stage. Any ideas for getting around this?

Comment: Try using `sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()`.  Scale your training features to `[0,1]`

Comment: Or try [non-negative matrix factorization](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html) (NMF) instead of LSA, or an SVM instead of naive Bayes.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend you that don't use Naive Bayes with SVD or other matrix factorization because **Naive Bayes based on applying Bayes' theorem with strong (naive) independence assumptions between the features**. Use other classifier, for example RandomForest

I tried this experiment with this results:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5, stop_words='english', use_idf=True)
lsa = NMF(n_components=100)
mnb = MultinomialNB(alpha=0.01)

train_text = vectorizer.fit_transform(raw_text_train)
train_text = lsa.fit_transform(train_text)
train_text = Normalizer(copy=False).fit_transform(train_text)

mnb.fit(train_text, train_labels)
```

This is the same case but I'm using NMP(non-negative matrix factorization) instead SVD and got 0,04% accuracy.

Changing the classifier MultinomialNB for RandomForest i got 79% accuracy.

**Therefore change the classifier or don't apply a matrix factorization.**

Comment: Don't forget to import the [NFM] [1] with `from sklearn.decomposition import NMF`

  [1]: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this in `fit()`

```
train_text.np.todense()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same isse running on NB, and indeed using `sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()` suggested by gobrewers14
works. But it actually reduced the performance accuracy on my Decision Tree, Random Forest and KNN by 0.2% from the same standardized dataset.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30047380)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a pipeline with Normalization as the first step and model fitting as the second step.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
p = Pipeline([('Normalizing',MinMaxScaler()),('MultinomialNB',MultinomialNB())])
p.fit(X_train,y_train)
```